# is there any way to compile some specific forms of C# project

Tags: c#

I'm working on a windows forms application with eight forms and I want to have different versions of the compiled application. For example:

Demo version: I want form1, form2, form4, form5
Full version: I want form1, form3, form4, form6, form8

How do I do that?

Comment: Make an extra project for demo release, **place the 2 project files (.csproj) inside the same folder**, and add the files (form1..etc) you want to included in the demo release to the new project.

Comment: Is "two different project files, one with a subset of the code files" a viable option?

Comment: Tell us how you define your app as in Demo or Full? Do you have serial keys? Registry entries?

Comment: @MarcGravell i prefer to have one project for later updates

Comment: @RonaldEstacion i dohave serial keys and etc. but i really cant rely on serial keys and registry entries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve that with single project by editing .csproj file. Just move forms to the separate `ItemGroup` elements with `Condition` attribute based on project `Configuration`:

```
<ItemGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Demo' ">
  <Compile Include="Form1.cs">
    <SubType>Form</SubType>
  </Compile>
  <Compile Include="Form1.Designer.cs">
    <DependentUpon>Form1.cs</DependentUpon>
  </Compile>
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Full' ">
  <Compile Include="Form2.cs">
    <SubType>Form</SubType>
  </Compile>
  <Compile Include="Form2.Designer.cs">
    <DependentUpon>Form2.cs</DependentUpon>
  </Compile>
</ItemGroup>
```

Also for these conditions to work you will need to create `Demo` and `Full` configurations using solutions's Configuration Manager.

Comment: Adding one small issue, we have faced in our VB app earlier. If you are using something like Me.MainForm = Global.MyProject.Form1 in OnCreateMainForm event of application  then the Form1 will be required in both item groups, else missing one will not be compiled. This will throw exception like 'Form1' is not a member of 'configurableBuild'

Comment: @OpenMinded Thanks. That really seems to be what i want. i will try it

Answer (score 1):

You could create them as different projects, but add the same code files to each:

- Add existing file to demo project
- Select the form file from the full version
- Add as link

[image]

Comment: Add a screenshot since this feature is hidden deep in VS.

Answer (score 0):

Compiler flags. Moving the forms into separate assemblies and repplacing them. Putting all forms int othe same program and have a factory select the right one (again listley based on a license key or a compiler flag).

Comment: These are individual suggestions, correct? Would it perhaps be better to present it in a bullet list?

Comment: @TomTom Can you give some more explanation?

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this demo using CDKEY 00 full version 11, then encrypt that key md5 hash maybe then write that in registry key, when the program runs it read first that key sample  if(cdkey==11){ //full version } else { //demo  }.